# ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(15129, 10, 1)

Tags: python, neural-network, rnn, reshape

I'm having a problem with reshaping a DataFrame, after doing this

```
train_dane_rnn = np.reshape(train_dane, (train_dane.shape[0], train_dane.shape[1], 1))
test_dane_rnn = np.reshape(test_dane, (test_dane.shape[0], test_dane.shape[1], 1))
```

I'm getting this error

```
ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(15129, 10, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert your DataFrame to a numpy array first.

Try this:

```
train_dane_rnn = np.reshape(np.array(train_dane), (train_dane.shape[0], train_dane.shape[1], 1))
test_dane_rnn = np.reshape(np.array(test_dane), (test_dane.shape[0], test_dane.shape[1], 1))
```